# Jupyter Notebook Folder with spaces on its name gives [Errno 2] No such file or directory when using "Save As"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, whitespace

When I try to save my code using the "Save as" function, I get the [Errno 2] No such file or directory, because my folders have whitespaces on their names, which get replaced by "%20" by Jupyter notebook. Hence, I have to manually change the "%20" by spaces in the path I want to save it in. How do I prevent Jupyter from mistaking whitespaces for "%20"?

Example:
If my folder is "New Folder", it tries to save it in "New%20Folder", so it thinks the path doesn't exist.